# Data streams in case of Merge

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

We are seeing enormous amounts of data-traffic  to and fro our SSIS server. We cannot find the culprit. Is there any way to find out which package is causing all the trafffic? Any advice on that? We are thinking that maybe all the merges we do cause all the traffic. Our SSIS machine gets data from several production SQL servers, merges that with  data in our warehouses. Dies that mean that

- a) new data is transfered to the SSI machine,
- b) existing data is    transferred  to the SSIS machine,
- c) Merge is done and then all data    is transferred  to the
  warehouse?

Then how would you go about limiting all the data moved from and to?

Comment: I see this is tagged as Azure so I am not sure on what limits of Profiler you have.  Could you clarify which server has what version?

Comment: Yes I can. A package collects data from different servers (varying from SQL 2008 to SQL 2014 to SQL Azure). That data is merged with existing data in SQL Azure databases. The SSIS machine is a SQL Server 2014 but we are seeing the same thing on a SQL 2012

Comment: It would make sense that the merges cause additional traffic.  After all it has to pull down the data to compare it with other data in the pipeline.  Are you limiting the scope of the merge or just doing full table merges?

Comment: By "merge" do you mean a) SSIS Merge Transformation, b) SQL MERGE statement, c) other (elaborate).

Comment: It's a SQL MERGE statement in a 'Execute SQL Task'. For now full table merges are done. What would be the best way to limit the scope of the merges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your questions a, b and c (if you're using SSIS transformation components in SSIS) is essentially “yes, all new data and existing data required for transformation will flow into SSIS instance, and the resulting merged data will flow out of SSIS instance to the target server”. More detailed explanation is below.

Assuming that you are using SQL Server 2012 and above, you would be able to enable Verbose logging to capture the number of rows transferred. The details are captured in [catalog].[execution_data_statistics]. If you are looking for the size in bytes, you would need to calculate that based on the columns that are being extracted and transformed against the number of rows.  The [catalog].[execution_data_statistics] captures package name, task name, data flow path and source/destination component name, the time of execution and execution path, which is great for diagnosing.

SSIS is an in-memory pipeline. If you have 3 separate servers, Source, SSIS and Target, the amount of data/traffic will vary. As an example, if the Data Flow Tasks  require transformation and use components such as Merge, Merge Join, Lookup etc, you can expect data flowing from Source Server, SSIS Server and Target Server.

On the other hand if you are running a simple Data Flow Task with SQL Server Destination for the Target between 2 databases with the same source and target, SSIS will issue a BULK INSERT statement on the target (= source = SSIS server) instance. In this case, there will be very low data traffic across the network (at least not related to the BULK INSERT statement).

If your package contains an “Execute SQL Task” component that invoke MERGE t-sql statements, this would not cause data traffic into/out of SSIS Server. The activity will be done on the SQL Server instance that the MERGE statement is executed on. If you are using Linked Servers, then the data will flow into/out of linked server as required by the MERGE statement just the same way as if you're invoking the statement on the instance.

My recommendation for limiting the amount of data moved from and to, is to be selective at the source level. For example, if you know that you are only going to be using ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC in dbo.Customer, then use

```
SELECT [ColumnA], [ColumnB], [ColumnC]  FROM [dbo].[Customer] --
Better!
```

instead of the following statement which potentially can retrieve more than those 3 columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Customer]  -- Do Not Use
```

There are also a number of best practices to optimize SSIS including reducing bandwidth and optimizing the amount of data transferred, that you can follow. Please have a read here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2013/09/16/top-10-sql-server-integration-services-best-practices.aspx.
If you are working on Hybrid platform, you may also be interested in reading "SSIS for Azure and Hybrid Data Movement" white paper (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj901708.aspx). This white paper has an additional link to "SSIS Operational and Tuning Guide" that would be useful as well.

In addition, you may also be interested in having a look at SSIS Reporting Pack available on CodePlex to get more visualization of SSIS executions on the server.

Hope this helps.
Julie

Comment: Thanks Julie! (We are already using  the SSIS Reporting Pack by the way)